# Custom Angular validator conflicts with Input mask

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-validation, angular-validator

I've created the following Angular 5 validator:

```js
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
import * as cpf from '@fnando/cpf';

export class Validador {

    static cpf(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        // https://github.com/fnando/cpf
        return cpf.isValid(control.value) ? null : {cpfInvalido: true};
    }
}
```

This validator works perfectly, except when I uso it together with a custom directive that applies Input mask (https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).

The directive is the following:

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var Inputmask;
@Directive({
  selector: '[mascara]'
})
export class MascaraDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() mascara: any;
    constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        Inputmask({ // https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask
            mask: this.mascara,
            skipOptionalPartCharacter: ' '
        }).mask(this.element.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Input with mask directive (the mask works, but validation stops working because can't handle the input value):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CPF" formControlName="cpf" mascara="999.999.999-99">
```

What could be wrong?

**EDIT:**

Adding the form builder:

```
this.personForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  cpf: ['', [Validators.required, Validador.cpf]],
  phone: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern('^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,3})+$')]],
  password: ['', Validators.required],
  addressStreet: ['', Validators.required],
  addressNumber: ['', Validators.required],
  addressZipcode: ['', Validators.required],
  addressNeighborhood: ['', Validators.required],
  addressObservation: ['', Validators.required],
  idState: [null, Validators.required],
  addressCity: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

Comment: can you paste your validation code? Where it's not working?

Comment: @SandipJaiswal I edited the question and added more information

Comment: paste this code in html and see the result: <div> Result: {{ personForm.get("cpf").valid }} and also debug your validationService that is it really giving null or {cpfInvalido: true}

Comment: Without the input mask, the result is false when is invalid or true when is valid. With the input mask, the result is ever false. The same occurs in other fields that only use required validator. This leads me to believe that the problem is in the mask itself, but I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the directive as follows (https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/1317#issuecomment-341872101)

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {NgControl} from '@angular/forms';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

declare var Inputmask;
@Directive({
  selector: '[mascara]'
})
export class MascaraDirective implements OnChanges {

    @Input() mascara: any;
    @Input('mascaraParams') options: any;
    constructor(private element: ElementRef, @Optional() private control: NgControl) { }

    ngOnChanges(): void { 
        if (!this.control) {
            console.warn('No control for InputMaskDirective');
            return;
        }

        if (this.mascara) {
            const options: any = _.clone(this.options) || {};
            _.defaults(options, { showMaskOnHover: false });
            options.oncomplete = options.onincomplete = options.oncleared = () => this.handleChange();
            Inputmask(this.mascara, options).mask(this.element.nativeElement);
        } else {
            Inputmask.remove(this.element.nativeElement);
        }
    }

    private handleChange(): void {
        this.control.control.patchValue(this.element.nativeElement.value);
    }
}
```